How to open up remote file through code CLI (terminal) while connected via remote tunnel
I set up a remote tunnel in Visual Studio Code using Microsoft's Remote - Tunnels extension. I am able to connect to it and use the integrated terminal.
Is it possible to run a command in the integrated terminal that will open up a file in the local VS code desktop environment? For example, running something like:
code file.txt

I only installed the CLI, so when I run the command above this is what I see:
No installation of Visual Studio Code stable was found.


Please do not tag Visual Studio for VS Code questions?

Either I'm understanding the question/context wrong, or you're looking at a bug. According to this maintainer comment by Connor, this should be supported:

When you connect a VS Code UI to a remote server, we inject a 'fake' "code"/"code-insiders" command in that terminal so that commands like code foo.txt open foo.txt in the remote UI. This is the command that doesn't have tunnel support yet, and it's a higher priorty than any other "code" command that might be in your PATH.

If I've understood this right, I think you'd want to raise an issue ticket.
Turns out it's a known issue that has to do with PATH priority. See Remote code command precedence on PATH #4451. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
